# Unable to interpret recursive loop output

Tags: loops, recursion

i am unable to guess the output after 'Hello 1' below. Why does system print 0-9 integers?

```
public static void number(int count) {
            if(count==0) 
                return;
            else {
                    System.out.println("Hello "+count);
                    number(--count);
                    System.out.println(count);
                    return;
                }

        }
public static void main(String args[]){
number(10);
}
```

Comment: Show the output.

Answer (score 0):

After printing:

`Hello 1`

your code does:

```c
number(--count); # number(--1) <==> number (0)
```

And then:

```c
if(count==0)
    return;
```

So it stops on `1` and does not print `0`, finishing the computation due to the `return`.